# Javascript Change div background if the values of a css element is equal to

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have several CSS classes with different background and i want to change the classes if the backgroundcolor  body is for example equals to #fc4477

Comment: `(if body background == *****) body addclass *****` ?

Comment: i try to explain better (sorry for my terrible english)

i'd like to dynamically change the background url image of a div in response of the color change  of an HTML element selected by the user..

If the user hypothetically select for the text logo color #Fc4477 my  logo-image change from 'logo1.png' to 'logo2.png'

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery function [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

and get the value of processed css rule, match with your value ad do what you need